# Class method can not call other class methods within the same class

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I have a class defined with two methods:

```
class A:
    def called():
        print 'called'
    def caller(self):
        called()
```

But caller can not use called directly

```
A().caller()
```

gives error

```
NameError: global name 'called' is not defined
```

How can I call the other unbounded method within the same class ?

Comment: Please review your indentation - as it stands, those functions are not defined in the class.

Answer (score 4):

Qualify the method with `self` or the class name `A`.

```
class A:

    @staticmethod
    def called():
        print 'called'

    def caller(self):
        self.called()
        # Or
        A.called()
```

**NOTE** I changed the method `called` as a static method.